# Orbeon: format number in template parameter

Tags: orbeon

I am working on an Orbeon form where the user needs to confirm the values of some input fields before being allowed to send in the form. The confirmation uses single checkboxes to allow different error messages.

The number formatting throughout the form is with comma as decimal separator and point as thousands separator.

Now, when I add the needed cell names as template parameters to a label to a single checkbox, the number from the cell is shown with point as decimal separator and no thousands separator, even though it is shown correctly in the original field and in the pdf?

So, how can I change this formatting of the number in a template parameter?

I tried format-number(//cell,"99.999,00") in the template parameter.

I also tried converting the number to a string and replace the point with a comma. It just seems like there must be a simpler solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, replacing `$number` with the reference to the value you want to display.

```
translate(
    format-number(xs:decimal($number),'#,##0.00'),
    ',.',
    '.,'
)
```

Credit: OP suggested technique using `translate()`.

Comment: Thanks, your example works :)

Can I somehow add a custom number format. In my case, I need the decimal separator to be comma, and the grouping separator to be point, like in this example: [https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_decimal-format.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_decimal-format.asp) ?

Comment: I tried combining your suggestion with the translate command, and this gives me the output I need (comma as decimal separator, point as grouping separator):

`translate(translate(translate(format-number(xs:decimal($number),'#,##0.00'), ',', '-'),".",","),"-",".")`

Where comma is replaced with hyphen, then point is replaced with comma and ultimately the hyphens are replaced with points. It works, but I am open to more elegant ways :)

Comment: @swordMan7000 Have you already tried `format-number(xs:decimal($number),'#.##0,00')`?

Comment: @swordMan7000 Did you get a chance to try the expression I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes, I did, but the text field did not show anything. A copy of the text field with format-number(xs:decimal($number),'#,##0.00') as the calculated value worked fine.

Comment: For some reason it seems that the installation of Orbeon that I am using does not accept anything but "." as decimal mark in a format-number formula. I tried other characters, e.g. "`", ":", "_" and "-", but none of them could work as a decimal mark either.

The version of Orbeon I use is: 2021.1.9.202306062351 PE

Comment: @swordMan7000 You're absolutely right! You can't use `#.##0,00` as the picture format. In fact, `format-number()` is an XSLT function, and the way to do this in XSLT is to define a decimal format with `<xsl:decimal-format name="european" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>`, to which you give a name, here `european`, and then refer to that format in `format-number(1234567.89, '#.###,00', 'european')`.

But here we can't define that format because we're not in XSLT, so I think your technique of using `translate()` is the way to go.

Comment: @swordMan7000 However, you can simplify your call to `translate()`: I have updated my answer above to include this simplified version.

Comment: Awesome! Your suggestion solves the problem perfectly :)

Comment: @swordMan7000 Excellent, I'm glad it works, and thanks for the confirmation!